# sqlalchemy connection flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the following code in flask

```
sql = text('select * from person')

results = self.db.engine.execute(sql)

for row in results:
    print(".............", row) # prints nothing
    
    
people = Person.query.all()  # shows all person data
```

Now given this situation, it's obvious, the self.db is not using the same connection somehow that Person.query is using. However, given this situation, can I get the connection somehow from Person.query object?

PS. This is for testing and I'm using SQLite3 database. I tried this in postgres, but outcome is the same.

Comment: Try `results = self.db.engine.execute(sql).fetchall()`

Comment: just tried it, doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out. Try Person.query.session.execute(sql). Voila!

Comment: Maybe try `session.query(Person).all()` (if you want to avoid using SQL query string).